# How do I find a comment?

Tags: support, comments, search

There's a question I wrote a comment on, but didn't provide an answer to.

I've forgotten the title on the question.  How can I locate it?

If I had provided an answer, it would appear in my history, and I could order it by most recent and locate it that way. But this technique won't work in this case.

Is there a way to search for questions I have commented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click the "Activity" tab on your profile page, you can limit the display to *Comments only* by clicking the "Comments" button just below the "Activity" tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I would mark it accepted. I almost asked the exact same question and your answer helped me find the comment I made on ServerFault.