# Add Ability To Search Comments Only

Tags: feature-request, search

### Request:

Can we add the ability to search only comments?

### Motivation:

Sometimes I remember a question or answer not by the body text or title, but by the comments.  These comments might be by me or someone else.  When I want to refer to these questions later, it is difficult to find them.  This would be easier if we could search in only comments.

I have been spending much more time reviewing than answering questions lately.  Once of the most frequent issues I find with questions -- especially those by new users -- is they don't post a minimal, complete example that replicates the problem they are having.  I know I have seen other people suggest very effectively that the questioner post a better question, and I'd like to see what they have recommended, and how the worded it.  If I do a search for "+ complete + minimal" however, I get a lot of noise.  If it were possible to search only comments, it would be much easier.

### Recommended Syntax:

Following the [precedent set](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for searching only body text, one possible syntax for this search method might be:

```
comment: apples oranges
```

### Related Questions on Meta:

1. [How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23771/how-can-i-search-stackoverflow-comments)
2. [How do I find a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79283/how-do-i-find-a-comment)

Comment: FWIW, [Jeff wants it too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23786/168660)

Comment: You're writing *"only"*. As far as I know, there's no way to search comments (through these sites) *at all*, right?

Comment: @Arjan: As far as I can tell, no.  I just tried both using the SO search feature and some google-fuism and neither resulted in a hit from yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

Short of a 'search comments' feature, sometimes Google comes to the rescue.

I was looking for a discussion about the system banner and the only thing I could remember is saying "Awe, shucks" in a comment (strange, I know). So I searched:

> Google:
>
> [site:meta.stackoverflow.com Robert Cartaino Awe shucks](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+Robert+Cartaino+awe+shucks)

Worked like a charm

Comment: Has anything changed with this feature-request since the new elasticsearch?

Comment: As an alternative, can we show ALL comments to the Google bot then...? (And maybe even a user id, which makes searching easier for those without a last name as nice as yours!)