# SE "search" does not seem to include comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, search

Just noticed this today, not sure if it's expected:

The reason I'd be in favor of including comments in the search is then you have a higher chance of finding what you're looking for, based on synonyms people might use, etc.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+would+suggest+adding+the+word%22

I would have expected to find this link:

[Hot Meta Posts: Allow for removal by moderators, and thoughts about future improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353492/hot-meta-posts-allow-for-removal-by-moderators-and-thoughts-about-future-impro)

Comment: If information in a comment is so vital it needs to be found by searching for it.  It probably should exist within a question and/or answer that it was submitted against.

Comment: Related: "[Add Ability To Search Comments Only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113621)" | "[How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771)" | "[Ability to search comments would be useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183142)" | "[Add Ability To Search Comments Only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113621)" | "[Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363470/282094)